# How to find the asymptotes of $(x^2-y^2)(x-y)=1$

Tags: calculus

I know how to do this when $y$ can be written in terms of $x$, but how do we find the asymptotes in the case of the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite it in the following way.

$$1=\frac{1}{(x-y)^2(x+y)}$$

You are looking cases where the denominator of the fraction on the right equals $0$

So this is when

$x=y$ or $x=-y$

Thus, your 2 asymptotes are $y=x$ and $y=-x$

Comment: Would this technique work if the equation were $(x^2-y^2)\sin(x) = 1$?  (No, it would not.)

Answer (score 0):

hint...consider a rotation of this curve and plot $u$ and $v$ where $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$